# Filtering a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ListBox named `lsbEntities`. I want to filter it's items based on some selected radio button.

The code below is kind of pseudo, is their a better approach?

```
private List<string> _listBoxItemsToFilter;
private Thread tFilterEntityList;

enum EntityType
{
    Vehicle,
    Facility
}

private void FilterEntityList(EntityType entityType)
{
    _listBoxItemsToFilter = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string,string> entitiesAndClassTypes;
    List<string> listBoxItems = new List<string>();

    for(int i = 0; i < lsbEntities.Count; i++)
    {
        //object listItem = lsbEntities.Items[i];           
        listBoxItems.Add(lsbEntities[i].ToString());    
    }

    // get associated types
    entityClassTypes = _controlFacade.GetClassTypes(listBoxItems);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string>
            entityAndClass in entitiesAndClassTypes)
    {
        classType = entityAndClass.Value;

        if(classType != entityType)
        {
                _listBoxItemsToFilter.Add(entityAndClass.Key);          
        }
    }

    RemoveFilterFromEntityListBox();
    AddFilterToEntityListBox();
}

private void AddFilterToEntityListBox()
{
    // DELEGATE NEEDED TO MODIFY LISTBOX FROM THREAD
    foreach(string listBoxItem in _listBoxItemsToFilter)
    {
        if(lsbEntities.Contains(listBoxItem)
        {
            // REMOVE WITH DELEGATE
        }
    }
}

private void RemoveFilterFromEntityListBox()
{
    // DELEGATE NEEDED TO MODIFY LISTBOX FROM THREAD
    if(_listBoxItemsToFilter != null)
    {
        foreach(string listBoxItem in _listBoxItemsToFilter)
        {
            if(!lsbEntities.Contains(listBoxItem)
            {
            // REMOVE WITH DELEGATE
            }
        }
    }
}

 // EXAMPLE CALL WHEN CLICKING RADIO-BUTTON
 private void rbVehicles_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     switch (rbVehicles.Checked)
     {
         case (true):
         {
             object entityType = (object)EntityType.Vehicle;
             tFilterEntityList = new Thread(FilterEntityList(entityType));
             tFilterEntityList.IsBackground = true;
             tFilterEntityList.Start(); 
             //FilterEntityList(EntityType.Vehicle);
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

I have only included an example of selecting to filter everything but `Vehicle`S. The same approach would be used for the `Facility` class, where the thread would be re-instantiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example showing one way to filter items in a ListBox. This could be improved by using a ListView or DataGridView in VirtualMode. It is very unclear to me what you are trying to do, so if this is not helpful I will remove it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    List<Entity> items = new List<Entity>()
    {
        new Entity(EntityType.Vehicle, "Car"),
        new Entity(EntityType.Vehicle, "Aeroplane"),
        new Entity(EntityType.Vehicle, "Truck"),
        new Entity(EntityType.Vehicle, "Bus"),
        new Entity(EntityType.Facility, "Garage"),
        new Entity(EntityType.Facility, "House"),
        new Entity(EntityType.Facility, "Shack"),
    };

    ListBox listBox;
    ComboBox comboBox;

    public Form1()
    {
        Text = "Filtering Demo";
        ClientSize = new Size(500, 320);
        Controls.Add(listBox = new ListBox
        {
            Location = new Point(10, 10),
            Size = new Size(200, 300),
        });
        Controls.Add(comboBox = new ComboBox
        {
            Location = new Point(230, 10),
            DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList,
            Items = { "All", EntityType.Vehicle, EntityType.Facility },
            SelectedIndex = 0,
        });

        comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += UpdateFilter;
        UpdateFilter(comboBox, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    void UpdateFilter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var filtered = items.Where((i) => comboBox.SelectedItem is string || (EntityType)comboBox.SelectedItem == i.EntityType);
        listBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(filtered, "");
    }
}

enum EntityType { Vehicle, Facility, }

class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public EntityType EntityType { get; private set; }
    public Entity(EntityType entityType, string name) { EntityType = entityType; Name = name; }
    public override string ToString() { return Name ?? String.Empty; }
    // Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to eliminate (caught) BindingSource exceptions
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: I used a BindingSource because it simplifies the code. I could have cleared the ListView's items list and repopulated it with the filtered list. How you get the unfiltered list isn't really relevant to filtering, which is what I thought you were asking about.

Comment: thank-you; your answer provides a clean way to easily change the content of a ListBox. My answer just contains the comparative logic required to determine what should and shouldn't be filtered (by querying the external application). I'm also using a Thread to keep my GUI responsive, therefore I use a single collection (_listBoxItemsToFilter), visible to each CheckedChanged handler. Can you see anything wrong with my approach? I have not had much experience with Lambda expressions and binding sources.. I will look into this.

Comment: One way to keep the UI responsive when dealing with large lists is to use a ListView or DGV in VirtualMode. In that mode the control asks you what the items are, and does so only at the moment it needs to display something. This way the control doesn't need to have its items list fully realized every time it changes.